# How to start dask cluster on this supercomputer?

Tags: python, dask, hpc, failed-installation, dask-distributed

I am trying to start a Dask cluster on 4 nodes with 32 cores each. The Intel MPI given does not allow forking processes, hence I disabled `nanny`. The interface is fast InfiniBand. I tried to start it with `tcp` protocol and with `ucx` protocol.

NFS locking is also disabled, and hence in config I added:

```
use-file-locking: False
```

With TCP protocol I get in logs:

```
waiting to connect to tcp://ip:port
```

I built UCX and UCX-PY. With UCX protocol I get in logs:

```
[1592509288.112709] [hostname:21579:1]      sockcm_ep.c:143  UCX  ERROR failed to connect to ip:port
```

Let me know how can I start the Dask cluster.

The command for `tcp`:

```
mpirun --np 4 /home/harsh/packages/Python-3.8/bin/dask-mpi \
       --no-nanny                                           \
       --interface ib0                                       \
       --memory-limit 115GB                                   \
       --scheduler-file /home/harsh/scheduler.json             \
       2>&1 | tee /home/harsh/dask_output.txt
```

The command for `ucx`:

```
mpirun --np 4 /home/harsh/packages/Python-3.8/bin/dask-mpi \
       --no-nanny                                           \
       --interface ib0                                       \
       --protocol ucx                                         \
       --memory-limit 115GB                                    \
       --scheduler-file /home/harsh/scheduler.json              \
       2>&1 | tee /home/harsh/dask_output.txt
```

Comment: have you explored the mpi4py module suggested here?:
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html

Comment: mpi4py is already installed, I am using intel MPI compiler. I was following the same link you shared. Can you be specific about what you are suggesting?